# Maximal ideals of $\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z$, $\Bbb Z/10\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

***Question***: Find the maximal ideals for $R=$

a) $\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z$, b) $\Bbb Z/10\Bbb Z$ and c) $\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$

***My attempt***: Since all those rings are finite and commutative, the set of prime ideals is equal to the set of maximal ideals.

For a) the only prime ideal is $(0)$ because $n\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z$ for $n=2,3,4$ spans $1_R=1+5\Bbb Z=3\cdot(2+5\Bbb Z)=2\cdot(3+2+5\Bbb Z)=4\cdot(4+5\Bbb Z)$

b)  $5\Bbb Z/10\Bbb Z$ and $2\Bbb Z/10\Bbb Z=4\Bbb Z/10\Bbb Z=6\Bbb Z/10\Bbb Z=8\Bbb Z/10\Bbb Z$ are the two only maximal ideals.

Here $(0)\subsetneq I\subsetneq R$ is not maximal and also not prime because for example $(2+10\Bbb Z)\cdot(5+10\Bbb Z)=0+10\Bbb Z$

c) $2\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z\times2\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$ and $2\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z\times3\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$ are the only two maximal ideals

Comment: Looks really good.

Comment: @Wuestenfux Although I guess c) looks correct to 3 people, it's actually incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$2\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z\times2\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$ and $2\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z\times3\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$ are not maximal ideals of $\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$.

Modding out by the first one, you get $\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_3$, which clearly isn't a field. I'll let you work out the quotient by the second one to see it has the same flaw.

As I'm sure you will have no problem discovering, there are three maximal ideals:

$$2\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z\\ \Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z\times3\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z\\\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z\times2\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$$

In general, the maximal ideals of a finite product of commutative rings $\prod_{i=1}^n R_i$ are of the form $\prod_{i=1}^n I_i$ where $I_i\lhd R_i$ and for exactly one $j$, $I_j$ is a prime ideal of $R_j$ and $I_i=R_i$ for all $i\neq j$.

Comment: Well spotted, thanks!

Comment: @JohnCataldo Also, in the future, please consider the self-answered question format when you have a proof which you can't see any problem in.  It'll get you your feedback, don't worry! And you'd probably get votes/points for the solution too (once corrected), so it's win/win for everyone.

Comment: You mean just post the question and answer it right away?

Comment: @JohnCataldo Yes: that's totally acceptable in a case like this.  For some insight as to why, there's actually an active meta post on the issue: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29119/29335

Comment: @JohnCataldo Well, provided that you check to see if your question has been asked before. If you find your question already asked, you should consider posting your solution at that question.